# Reading a file in Linux using C

Tags: c, linux, file

I am attempting to open a file I have created called "inputs.txt" using ubuntu on Windows. In the Linux manual I found that the O_DIRECTORY flag is used for files in the same directory and will fail if they are not in that directory. I used this flag and saved the "inputs.txt" file in the same folder as my .c file. Any ideas why it is failing to open?

```
int main(){
    int fd;
    fd = open("inputs.txt", O_DIRECTORY);
    if (fd == -1){
        printf("Failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe you mis-read the manual.. Here's what it says on my Ubuntu 20.04: "O_DIRECTORY
              If pathname is not a directory, cause the open  to  fail."
Therefore, if "inputs.txt" is not a directory, open() will fail.
I assume, "inputs.txt" is a regular file, in the current directoryl

So, just do what @mhawke recommends.

Comment: `printf("Failed because %s\n", strerror(errno));`

Answer (score 3):

`O_DIRECTORY` is used to open a directory, not a regular file.

Just use `O_RDONLY` if you just want to read the contents of a regular file.